# How can i save the content of lable entry while click on a switch using pygtk

Tags: pygtk

```
import gtk

class PyApp(gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PyApp, self).__init__()

        self.set_title("Entry")
        self.set_size_request(300, 300)
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)

        fixed = gtk.Fixed()

        self.label = gtk.Label("Entry")
        fixed.put(self.label, 40, 40)

        entry = gtk.Entry()
        fixed.put(entry, 80, 40)

        self.button1 = gtk.Button("    OK  ")
        button1 = gtk.Button(stock=gtk.STOCK_CLOSE)
        fixed.put(self.button1, 130, 90)


        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.add(fixed)
        self.show_all()


PyApp()
gtk.main()
```

How to save this label entry as a text file?

Comment: Can you please clarify the problem? Not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the text of the GtkEntry after clicking the button, you have to connect to the `clicked` signal:

```
import gtk

class PyApp(gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PyApp, self).__init__()

        self.set_title("Entry")
        self.set_size_request(300, 300)
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)

        fixed = gtk.Fixed()

        self.label = gtk.Label("Entry")
        fixed.put(self.label, 40, 40)

        self.entry = gtk.Entry()
        fixed.put(self.entry, 80, 40)

        button1 = gtk.Button("OK")
        button1.connect('clicked', self.button_clicked)
        fixed.put(button1, 130, 90)


        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.add(fixed)
        self.show_all()

    def button_clicked(self, widget):
        with open('entry.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(self.entry.get_text())


PyApp()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Thanks a lot, for late few weeks am trying to do this this .